# Flex/Bison error: basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I have the following rule in my flex file:

```
{ID}        {printf("(id, \"%s\") [%d]\n", yytext, yylineno); yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return IDENT;}
```

And the following rule in my bison file:

```
identificador            : IDENT                            {cout << "identificador : IDENT\n"; cout << $1 << "\n";$$ = $1;}
```

When it tries to print `$1`, I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
```

what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

For me it looks like `$1` is `NULL`, but I don't see why.
Both files are really big, because the grammar is enormous, but I can edit to add other relevant parts if necessary.

Comment: Is this the only `flex` rule returning `IDENT`?

Comment: Yes, it is the only one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know the exact cause of the error but I managed to fix it by changing the `%union` declaration in the bison file.

Previously it was:

```
%union {

     int integer;

     char character;

     char* str;

     entry* e;


 };
```

Now it is:

```
%union {

     struct {

         int integer;

         char character;

         char* str;

         entry* e;

     };

 };
```

Comment: That would have been my next question. Good work you found it.

Comment: Your change will just allocate extra, unused space on the bison stack, but won't actually change what values are on the stack, so it will likely just move the problem around, rather than actually fixing it.  This (along with the original problem description) leads me to believe you have a memory corruption problem (writing through an invalid pointer or off the end of an array), so you might try something like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org)

Comment: Well, the whole program worked as I expected. I ran Valgrind just in case and it returned: ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)